# Cannot write samba shares

Tags: samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, selinux, rhel-6

Running samba 3.5 on Red Hat Enterprise 6.1 I'm having issues sharing two folders. Here is the output of `testparm`:

```
[global]
    workgroup = DOMAINNAME
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    interfaces = lo, eth1
    bind interfaces only = Yes
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    idmap uid = 16777216-33554431
    idmap gid = 16777216-33554431
    hosts allow = 10.50.183.48, 10.50.184.41, 10.50.184.199, 10.50.183.160, 127.0.0.1
    hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
    cups options = raw

[test]
    comment = test folder
    path = /usr/local/samba
    valid users = claudio
    write list = claudio
    force user = claudio
    read only = No
    create mask = 0775
    directory mask = 0775

[test2]
    comment = another test
    path = /home/claudio/tst
    valid users = claudio
    write list = claudio
    force user = claudio
    read only = No
    create mask = 0775
```

From the Windows XP machine I'm connecting from I'm able to read `test` but not write, while for `test2` I can't even access the folder (though I can see it listed).

```
ls -l /usr/local
...
drwxrwxrwx. 2 claudio claudio 4096 Dec  3 10:39 samba
...

ls -l /user/local/samba
total 32
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 claudio claudio    9 Nov 29 16:26 asd.txt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 claudio claudio  728 Dec  3 10:16 out.txt
...

ls -l /home/claudio/
...
drwxrwxr-x.  2 claudio claudio       4096 Dec  3 09:57 tst
...

ls -l /home/claudio/tst
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 claudio claudio 4 Dec  3 09:57 asd.txt
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Interestingly, I had to do both `read only = no` and `writeable = yes`, even though they appear synonymous. But I deleted the answer since you didn't think it would help.  But I was doing this last night and thought the same thing - which in my case that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat Enterprise comes with SELinux enabled by default, which provides an implementation of the *mandatory access control* mechanism ([as you can read from the guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Introduction.html)).

That means shared files/folders need to be labeled with the proper type in order to allow `smbd` to share them correctly (you can check it adding the option `Z` to the `ls` command). This is achieved through the command

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /path
```

which allow to write on the share (add the option `-R` to flag recursively).